# Split Regex anything but number

Tags: regex, split

I'm trying to do a **monthly installment** with some possibilities, like:

- 3x *// result == 3*
- 10x *// result == 10*
- 30 *// result == 1*
- 30./60 *// result == 2*
- 30@60@90 *// result == 3*
- 30 60 90 120 *// result == 4*
- 30-60- 90-120--150 *// result == 5*
- 30x60x90x120x150x180 *// result == 6*

and so on... I'm trying to get **any character**, with **multiple spaces** OR multiple characters (equals to each other or not). I reach the following code so far... but I could add the exception for numbers, and the result are not always right.

```js
var pattern = /(\#?[a-zA-Z(!0-9) \/]+)/g;
var a = '30/60/90';
var b = a.split(pattern);

$('#yyy').text(b);
$('#xxx').text(b.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="yyy"></label>
<br><br>
<label id="xxx"></label>
```

I'm HORRIBLE in regex, really "noob" to it, so if could explain in the answer/comment WHY you are doing specific regex, I would be please (so I can learn instead of copy/paste without too much clue)

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? This is a regexp question.

Comment: Regex is the closest solution for my problem (without the need to write 1000 lines of code to catch every exception), but I'm using jQuery in the project, so there is no obligation on pure JavaScript answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so sure I understood your question correctly, but I'll answer as I understood it:

To split on anything except numbers, the solution would be:

```js
var pattern = /\D+/g;
var a = '30/60/90';
var b = a.split(pattern);

$('#yyy').text(JSON.stringify(b));
$('#xxx').text(b.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="yyy"></label>
<br><br>
<label id="xxx"></label>
```

The regex is pretty simple: `\d` means *a digit*, so `\D` means *not a digit*, so `\D+` means *a series of characters that are not digits*.

It may be even easier if you try matching instead of splitting:

```js
var pattern = /\d+/g;
var a = '30/60/90';
var b = [];
var m;

while (m = pattern.exec(a))
    b.push(m[0]);

$('#yyy').text(JSON.stringify(b));
$('#xxx').text(b.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="yyy"></label>
<br><br>
<label id="xxx"></label>
```

In that case `\d+` means *a series of digits*.

For reference, in JS:

- `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]`
- `\D` is shorthand for `[^0-9]`

Comment: Amazing!! I loved the explanation and that is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!