# Recreate this jquery while in php

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code in my jQuery:

```
var pattern = /\d+/g;
var retorno = [];
var aux;
var inputTxt = "30/60/90"

while (aux = pattern.exec(inputTxt)){
    retorno.push(aux[0]);
}
```

I need to do something very similar in php, I was trying

`while ($aux = $pattern.exec($inputTxt)){` to `while ($aux = $pattern.exec($inputTxt)){` **To:**

```
preg_match($pattern, $frm_condicao_de_pagamento, $aux, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
for($i = 0; $i < count($aux); $i++){
```

But this error occurs: *"E_WARNING : type 2 -- preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'g' -- at line 5"* and I'm not even sure if I should be using `preg_match()`function to do this.

The idea of the code is to check if the data is (a Arithmetical progression OR numbers with a specific format (this is being tested inside the loop)).

So, the result should be: `array(30,60,90);`

Comment: Don't use `preg_match` with `/g`. Use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Why are you using a regex here?  Why not just `inputTxt.split('/')` or `explode('/', $inputTxt)`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat because the input may come as '30/60/90' but also as '30-60-90' or '30--60//90' or '30_60_90' or '30x60x90'... Besides, I need to collect when it is '30x' and '30d' **note that 30/60/90 are fictional numbers, they may come as 10/15/20 or 32/50/55 for instance. For more information, check my last question ["Split Regex anything but number"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639211/split-regex-anything-but-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **preg_match_all()** function to get all the matches for example(in this case you don't need to add the **g flag**) :

```
$str = "30/60/90" ;
$matches;
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

note here that i'm using () and \d inside, the goal of using () is to group the matches so you can access them using $1 $2 etc

Comment: I tested in the [PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/) and it return two identical arrays `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 60
            [2] => 90
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 60
            [2] => 90
        )

)`

Comment: yes i told you before if you remove () outiside the \d+ you will get the desired array but may be you want to access the matches by $1 $2 and this why i added the () for grouping reasons

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that part of your answer, my fault. Thanks this is what I needed. =)